# React.js how to call method on child component through refs?

Tags: coffeescript, reactjs

I have a `CustomerForm` component like so:

```
@CustomerForm = React.createClass
  getInitialState: ->
    name: ''
    street: ''
    location: ''
    addendum: ''

  render: ->
    React.DOM.form
      className: 'ui form'
      React.DOM.div
        className: 'field'
        React.DOM.label null, 'Name'
        React.DOM.input
          type: 'text'
          name: 'name'
          value: @state.name
          onChange: @handleChange
      React.DOM.div
        className: 'field'
        React.DOM.label null, 'Address'
        React.DOM.div
          className: 'three fields'
          React.DOM.div
            className: 'field'
            React.DOM.input
              type: 'text'
              name: 'street'
              placeholder: 'Street'
              value: @state.street
              onChange: @handleChange
          React.DOM.div
            className: 'field'
            React.DOM.input
              type: 'text'
              name: 'location'
              placeholder: 'Location'
              value: @state.location
              onChange: @handleChange
          React.DOM.div
            className: 'field'
            React.DOM.input
              type: 'text'
              name: 'addendum'
              placeholder: 'Addendum'
              value: @state.street
              onChange: @handleChange

  handleChange: (e) ->
    @setState "#{e.target.name}": e.target.value

  valid: ->
    @state.name && @state.street && @state.location
```

As you can see it exposes a method called `valid()`. I also have a `CustomerModal` component which is a semantic-ui modal dialog that renders the form:

```
@CustomerModal = React.createClass
  render: ->
    React.DOM.div
      className: 'ui active modal'
      React.DOM.i className: 'close icon'
      React.DOM.div className: 'header', 'Customer'
      React.DOM.div
        className: 'content'
        React.createElement(CustomerForm, ref: 'form')
      React.DOM.div className: 'actions',
        React.DOM.button
          type: 'submit'
          disabled: !@refs.form.valid()
          'Submit'
```

As given by the [semantic-ui's modal markup](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/modal.html#actions) I'd like to have the submit button on the `CustomerModal` component. In addition I would like that submit button to be disabled as long as the form is not valid, hence calling `valid()` on the `CustomerForm` component, because the component itself should determine if it's valid or not.

However, when I try to use the `@refs` object in the above way, I always get the error `TypeError: this.refs.form is undefined`

I am quite new to Ract.js and this is part of my learning experience with it in a small Rails project, using CoffeeScript.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to use  React's `refs` to access direct descendants.

You can maintain direct references in scope.

Aside, you might benefit from something like

```
{form, div, label, input} = React.DOM
```

You wouldn't use refs the way you have anyway.  Always you can get the component with `findDOMNode` over the ref as an identifier.  Then with that reference you could call a component function.

Notice the `React.findDOMNode` line
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#completing-the-example

**ae final prognosis:**
I think it's like in the docs where they say "if you find yourself wondering how to make crazy Calder mobiles geometry with refs, maybe it's time to rethink your data structure."  Of course they say "state", and then you are off to learn Immutables and Flux.  And if you get really advanced you can sometimes drop React completely and just use Flux, with WebGL.  My opinion.
https://github.com/Terebinth/Vickers is my latest complete React codebase.

Comment: Thanks, yes I've seen this shorthand components already. Could you give me a short code example, cause I'm totally lost here...

Comment: If you want to call `valid` function from a descendant, you can pass it as a prop.  I'll get an example in a minute.  I'm still trying to make sure I understand what you want to do.  just a min.

Comment: So actually you should be holding state higher up.  You can do this with refs by getting the component first with `React.findDOMNode` but really you need to rethink where you are putting state.

Comment: Hmm... but why? Isn't the whole point of that concept to be able to reuse components anywhere? I realized that I could simply make it one component `CustomerForm` and have the whole form be the modal dialog as well, then I wouldn't have this problem... but what if I want to use that form later on as an inline form without the modal?

Comment: I'll look at it again.

Comment: So I'm looking at it again (a realtime comms context might be better here, but whatever) and (~question_000): why isn't state in the parent (modal) rather than the child (form)?  You can pass functions, and view data can be passed as props.  React propogates change through render cycles, which are triggered by among other things @setState calls.

Comment: Just generally this codebase might be of use/interest: https://github.com/Terebinth/Vickers